# SQL INSERT with values from dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, sql

I have an SQL table that is loaded automatically but sometimes has Null values. I'd like to be able to update this table with values from a dataframe that's loaded from an excel file which may also be incomplete with Null values. `table` represents what data already is in my database, but there are also columns `create_timestamp` and `edited_timestamp` which are populated automatically. Only `a` and `b` columns can contain Null values. Also `df` will have only one value in `cond` column.

```
table = pd.DataFrame(
    [
      [1, 2, 3, 0],
      [4, None, 6, 0], 
      [1, None, None, 1], 
      [4, 11, None, 1]
    ], 
    columns=['code', 'a', 'b', 'cond']
)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
      [1, 8, 9, 1], 
      [4, 11, None, 1]
    ], 
    columns=['code', 'a', 'b', 'cond']
)
```

I'm unsure if it's possible, but I'm trying to achieve updating `table` with a single insert. I'm trying to achieve something in the lines of

```
query = f"""
INSERT INTO table (a, b)
<somehow iterate through <code>, if a is Null, then fill it with {df[df.code == code_iteration].a}, 
    if b is Null, then fill it with {df[df.code == code_iteration].b}>
WHERE cond = {df[cond].values[0]}
"""
```

Another idea is that I could retrieve `table` into dataframe, fill it with python, drop rows `where cond =  {df[cond].values[0]}` and append new rows. That would overwrite `create_timestamp' column though and I'd like to avoid that. I'm not sure if I could overwrite it with previous data that has been saved to loaded dataframe because it fills automatically every time a new row is added. I'd like to do it efficiently and know what would be the best practice here.

I'm sorry if I overcomplicated this, but I hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Another approach is to set up a ‘trigger’ on the database table which acts on row insert.  You can write the trigger such that if a value is null, the new value is populated, otherwise the already populated value is left alone.  Might be more straight-forward to let the DB handle this, rather than knocking something together externally.  For example, here are the docs to a [MySQL trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, but I'm unsure how to apply it to my case, also only 2 columns 'a' and 'b' would need to be checked for Null. Could you provide a working example for my data in question? Would the trigger work if I tried to df.to_sql() the whole df?

Comment: Yes, a `df.to_sql` function call can run the trigger, as the trigger can be set to run on the insert for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe CASE with WHEN THEN can help you to implement the logic.

More info: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/case-function-in-mysql/

As far as I know, using triggers in SQL is not the "best practice" pattern.

Comment: I guess that could work, but I would either have to somehow loop through all existing `code` in sql insert, or have a lot of "case when then" for every possible `code` since set of possible values is known. And then I'd want to check if value to insert is going into Null for `a` and `b` respectively. That sounds awful for the amount of code that needs to be written, and doesn't sounds like best practice either, but that's my subjective opinion.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is best to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. A code example can be very useful. Link-only responses may become invalid if the linked page changes.